# Pagination DRF not working well

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a little problem with pagination when I put the default pagination in my project, somethings pages work in others pages not working for example:

this is my file settings.py for all my project

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
            'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'apicolonybit.notification_clbt.NotificationPagination.PaginationList'}
```

this is my Configuration app inside my project: myproject / Configuration

```
class ConfigurationsList(generics.ListAPIView):
     """
        list configuration with current user authenticated.
      """
      queryset = Configuration.objects.all()
      serializer_class = ConfigurationSerializer
```

when I run this part in my postman, working well, but when I try to run in another module like this:

```
class TransactionListHistory(generics.ListAPIView):
      # queryset = TransactionHistory.objects.all()
      serializer_class = TransactionHistorySerializer
      pagination_class = PaginationList
      page_size = 2
      page = 1

     def get_object(self, current_user):
         # User.objects.get(id=pk)
         return TransactionHistory.objects.filter(agent_id=current_user.id).order_by('-id')

      @classmethod
      def get_object_client(cls, current_user, trans):
            # User.objects.get(id=pk)
          return TransactionHistory.objects.filter(user_id=current_user.id).order_by('-id')

    def get(self, request, format=None):
          current_user = request.user
          status_trans = 6
          agent_user = 2
          client_user = 1
          trans = {
            'status': status_trans
           }
          typeusers = Profile.objects.get(user_id=current_user.id)

        # actions agent user = show all transaction from all client users
         if typeusers.type_user == agent_user:
               list_trans_init = self.get_object(current_user)
               serializer = TransactionHistorySerializer(list_trans_init, many=True)
               get_data = serializer.data

    # actions normal user (client user) = just see transactions from self user
         if typeusers.type_user == client_user:
              list_trans_init = self.get_object_client(current_user, trans)
              serializer = TransactionHistorySerializer(list_trans_init, many=True)
              get_data = serializer.data

         # if not PaginationList.get_next_link(self):
         # return JsonResponse({'data': get_data}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
         return self.get_paginated_response(get_data)
```

my custom file pagination like this

```
class PaginationList(PageNumberPagination):
      page_size = 2 # when show me an error I added
      offset = 1 # when show me an error I added
      limit = 10 # when show me an error I added
      count = 10 # when show me an error I added
      page = 1 # when show me an error I added

     def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
               'next': self.get_next_link(),
               'previous': self.get_previous_link()
             },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
          })
```

the variables page_size and etc, then show me an error like PaginationList is not object page, I added this page_size and pass other error like PaginationList is not object offset and again added var.

well the last error show me is like this 'int' object has no attribute 'has_next'

please help me, how to add my custom pagination in my class TransactionListHistory

thanks for your attention.

Comment: can you add the error traceback?

Comment: AttributeError at /api/v1/transactions/list-history/
'int' object has no attribute 'has_next'

Request Method: GET

Comment: add the **full traceback**

Comment: I can't because the traceback is too long for this comment.

Comment: use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Looks like the last error you got was because `page=1` overwrites the DRF `PageNumberPagination.page` attribute which is supposed to be a `django.core.paginator.Page` object (not an integer).  It's a little hard to understand what your initial error was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **`self.get_paginated_response()`** in wrong way.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TransactionListHistory(generics.ListAPIView):
    # Your code

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = do_something_and_return_QuerySet()  # do some logical things here and 

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

the `do_something_and_return_QuerySet()` is fucntion or logic of you, which return a **`QuerySet`**.

**Example**

```
class TransactionListHistory(generics.ListAPIView):
    # Your code

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = TransactionHistory.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```